# if first column of first row contains "Region" word then make that entire row as header.how can i code this in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have multiple columns like

```
Region  | Canal |   Fabricantes|    Marcas  |Aromas Tamanos |   Año
```

like above so if 1st column of 1st row contains Region then make that row header of Dataframe otherwise dont do anythin...how can i code this in R?

Comment: Usually you can take care of the header row when you import the data, like `read.csv(your_file_path, header=TRUE)`

Comment: @KenHBS its not csv i am reading a xlsx file

Comment: You can also achieve this with .xlsx files. Which package are you using to read xlsx files?

Comment: @KenHBS i am using readxl package

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can achieve this while importing the data already. For example, if you are using the `openxl` package, you can make it read the first row as the column names like this:

```
library(openxl)

open_xlsx(path='your_filename.xlsx', col_names=TRUE)
```

If you do not want the first to be the column name, use `col_names=FALSE`.